# Unable to read output of a joystick on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: microcontroller, raspberry-pi, python, joystick

I connected my joystick with this tutorial: [link](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/04/using-a-joystick-on-the-raspberry-pi-using-an-mcp3008/)

However, it does not work. The code runs fine (after changing `print "---"` to  `print("---")` to support modern python), but the output values stay at 0.

```
X : 0  Y : 0  Switch : 0
```

This is my circuit. I checked it 2-3 times, seems fine.

**Notes:**

- "+" and "-" are reversed on my breadboard. I decided to stay consistent with marks on my breadboard, not the tutorial.
- pins on my joystick are different. (on my js, highest says "GND", second highest says "5W". bottom three output signals.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your diagram shows wires from the joystick going to MCP3008 pins 1, 2, and 3.  But in your photo it looks like they are connected to pins 2, 3, and 4.  Also double-check the wires providing power to the joystick because they don't match the diagram either.

Comment: Yep, but i just fixed it. Still does not work.

Comment: @kkrambo yes, I actually messed up the description of my js. I connected it properly, 2nd highest pin provides power.

Comment: Code? Are you setting up the pins correctly?

Comment: @RonBeyer code can be found in the link. I did not modify the layout.

Comment: Did you follow the SPI set up instructions?

Comment: Yes. I could not start the script before installing SPI.

Comment: It looks like you are powering the joystick with 3.3V.  But then you say the joystick power terminal says "5W".  Does the joystick work with only 3.3V?

Comment: Double check that RPi's MISO is connected to the MCP3008's DOUT and MOSI is connected to DIN.  Use a logic analyzer to observe the SPI signals to determine whether the program is controlling them correctly.

Comment: To debug the ADC inputs, disconnect the joystick and then see if your X, Y, and switch readings change when you connect the CH1, 2, and 3 pins to first GND and then _alternately_ 3.3V.  (Don't connect to both GND and 3.3V at the same time.)